# java compiler warning: readStrings() in In (deprecated)

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, deprecated

I'm running javac v1.6.0-65 in a Dr. Java studio on a Mac with OSX 10.9.1

I get the following warning:

```
Quick.java:53: warning: [deprecation] readStrings() in In has been deprecated
```

which isn't so bad, I guess, except I also get the following error:

```
Quick.java:54: sort(java.lang.Comparable[],int,int) in Quick cannot be applied to (java.lang.String[])
```

The code lines are:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ // Read strings from standard input, sort them, and print. 
   String[] a = In.readStrings(); 
   sort(a);
```

and

```
private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
{
```

There seems to be some mismatch in defining the array a of input, String[] a, as something that can be compared in the private sort(). I thought strings could be compared.

My question is, how do I get rid of the error?  And, incidentally, does the warning relate to the error?

Comment: So, you're trying to call a function which takes three arguments and you only provide one, then wonder why it doesn't work?

Comment: Also, note that you are using `Comparable` as a raw type.

Comment: Yeah, you make a good point, thanks.  Can you suggest an alternative to the deprecated readStrings() in In?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the deprecated warning, **don't use a deprecated function.** [Deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) functions may not meet current standards. They exist only to provide backwards compatibility while the rest of the world catches up. In your case, use another Stream reader instead. I prefer [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), but there are plenty more.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.In);
String[] strings = in.readLine().split(" ");
```

Java has a built in Arrays.Sort() method that you can use instead of implementing your own, unless you have some special requirements.

```
Arrays.sort(strings);
```

Comment: I'm new to this community so edit my comment out of existence if it doesn't fit with the social customs.  How should I deal with the following conundrum:  I would vote up the first half of this answer.  It factually answers the question - what alternatives are recommended for the deprecated function.  I would vote down the second half as an unsolicited opinion.  Of course, in a commercial environment where the performance characteristics of the standard Arays.sort() meet the needs of the expected input the opinion is valid.  However, in other realms, it isn't.  Hence, it's an opinion.